# php script to display a random image pulling their urls from a text file

Tags: php, image, random

I have this script in a file (called random.php) which displays a random image from the folder where it resides:

```
<?php 
$pics = glob('*.jpg', GLOB_NOSORT); 
$pic = $pics[array_rand($pics)]; 
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"" . basename($pic) . "\""); 
readfile($pic); 
?>
```

I am calling it as follows:

```
<img class="random" src="http://www.example.com/random.php" />
```

It works properly.

I want instead to make it to display random pictures by pulling their urls from a text file full with lines, each line being an image url.
How to do this?

Final update: This is what worked for me.

```
<?php 
$file = 'random.txt';

if (!is_readable($file)) {
    exit('File list does not exist, or is not readable by the webserver.');
}

$pics = file('random.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); 

$pic = $pics[array_rand($pics)]; 

if (!getimagesize($pic)) {
    exit('Image does not exist, or is not readable by the webserver.');
}

/// content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
// prevent caching (so its random)
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
//


readfile($pic); 
?>
```

Is the script kindly compiled below by Lawrence Cherone but commenting out the last header tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch out `glob('*.jpg', GLOB_NOSORT);` for [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

`$pics = file('/path/to/file.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

Try this, with added error checking:

```
<?php 
$file = 'random.txt';

if (!is_readable($file)) {
    exit('File list does not exist, or is not readable by the webserver.');
}

$pics = file('random.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); 

$pic = $pics[array_rand($pics)]; 

if (!getimagesize($pic)) {
    exit('Image does not exist, or is not readable by the webserver.');
}

// content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
// prevent caching (so its random)
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
//
header('Content-Disposition: filename="'.basename($pic).'"');

readfile($pic); 
?>
```

Comment: don't put code in comments, instead update your question with your **exact code**. your need to debug it, as whats happening is your outputting whitespace or file() is throwing an error (maybe permissions or not found) and when header is set it throws an error.

Comment: As you suggested I updated my original post with the code which needs debugging. Could you kindly write the complete script as it is supposed to be? I only know to copy and paste scripts, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @ Lawrence The content of random.txt is just two lines, each being an URL of an image hosted on google

Comment: @Konstantinos See updated code, i've tested it and it works fine.

Comment: @Konstantinos added some additional headers to stop browser caching.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it and it works as it should except that it only shows the last image from the list of the urls contained in the random.txt file: The other urls show as an empty box in chrome and on firefox it displays: The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors. I hope this could be fixed because otherwise, it works nicely. I changed the order of the urls several times and it was the same. Only the last url would be displayed as image. I put just one url and it was always working.